# Create new contact to Mailjet and adding to an existing list

Tags: email, mailjet

After subscription on my website form, I need to create the new contact on Mailjet and then add it to a specific list that already exist.

I have this following code which I execute after insert my user to database.

```
$firstname = "Michael";
$email = myemail@gmail.com;
$mj = new \Mailjet\Client($MJ_APIKEY_PUBLIC,$MJ_APIKEY_PRIVATE);

// create new contact on Mailjet
$contact_params = [
   "Email" => $email
]; 
$response_add = $mj->post(Resources::$Contact, ['body' => $contact_params]);

// adding the created contact to my list
$list_params = [
    'Name' => $firstname,
    'Action' => "addnoforce",
    'Email' => $email
];
                    
$response_list = $mj->post(Resources::$ContactslistManagecontact, ['id' => 10181436, 'body' => $list_params]);
```

The contact is correctly created on Mailjet but never add to the list. The `$response_list` always give me back NULL and I don't really know why. I'm pretty new with Mailjet API, but I've following the official API and the way I want to do it seems correct. (https://dev.mailjet.com/email/reference/contacts/subscriptions#v3_post_contactslist_list_ID_managecontact)

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you are yet to find a solution.
Try this out, it works for me.

Check the "/contactslist/{list_ID or list_address}/managecontact" section on this documentation; https://dev.mailjet.com/email/reference/contacts/subscriptions#v3_post_listrecipient

Enjoy